# How can an iframe fill a fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have set up a fancy  box (http://fancybox.net). It's box size resizes itself automatically to the size of the webbroser.

Now i want to have an iframe inside the box to resize itself along with the box.

I have searched responsive iframes but the examples show resposive iframes in relation to browser window.

What i am after is a solution allowing iframe to adjust itself to the box.

```
This is a simple link that is fired with jquery:
<body>
<a  class="Link"  file="game" srrc="video/voytox/index.html" 
caption="Caption" ></a>

and it opens an iframe within the fancybox

<iframe id ="Player"   ></iframe>
</body>

this is the jquery:
$('.Link').click(function(){
        var File = $(this).attr('file');
        var srrc = $(this).attr('srrc');
        //var videoWidth = Number($(this).attr('videowidth')); I can 
         optionally set fixed height and width, but i don't want to do that.
        //var videoHeight = Number($(this).attr('videoheight'));



        $('#Player').attr("src", srrc); //this refers to the iframe
```

This fires the fancybox. I set it at fixed width and height for testing purposes that is to check how the iframe fills the fancybox. Unfortunately at 100%, 
it exceeds the fancy box and it is not contained. I want it to be "subordinate"
to the size of the box.

```
        $.fancybox({
            'autoDimensions'    : false,
            'scrolling'         : 'no',
            'width'             : '800',
            'height'            : '800',
            'hideOnOverlayClick' : false,
            'transitionIn' :'fade',
            'transitionOut' :'fade',
            'overlayColor' :  '#666',
            'overlayOpacity': .9,
            'href' : '#videoPlayer'

             });
```

Comment: Can you post your code and what you've tried already? I assume putting the width and height of the iframe at 100% isn't working for you?

Comment: 100% makes it exceed the box size, i want it to be contained in the box.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the `iframe` to your fancybox - that way, when you assign a width of 100% it will be relative to its parent element. Currently they are siblings.

Comment: it seems it does not matter, i also did html() and passed the iframe with width 100% and height="100%". Only width got applied to full width of the box, height did not at all. However when i hardcoded different values like 50, 80 etc into height, the height did change. Thus i still do not know how to fill the fancy box with an iframe.

Comment: What i need to do is to set the iframe height to the box's height. How to achieve that?